# Where can i learn to create saleforces cli plugin?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, force-cli

I am new to salesforce and i am looking for any tutorial paid or not to learn to create salesforce cli plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through [Salesforce CLI Plug-In Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_plugins.meta/sfdx_cli_plugins/cli_plugins_generate.htm) to create your own plug-in. Below are some more reference to Blogs and Videos.

Blogs

[Build a Salesforce DX Plugin in 15 Min](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/build-a-salesforce-dx-plugin-in-15-minutes-dreamforce-2018/)

Videos

[Build and Release Salesforce CLI Plug-In](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QNNfgJp_Vg)